# while building android app , android studio says Gradle version 1.10 required.current version is 2.2.1

Tags: android, android-studio

I am trying to execute android project in android studio then i face this error

> Gradle version 1.10 is required. Current version is 2.2.1. If using the gradle wrapper

this is my wrapper properties :

> distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.2.1-all.zip

and gradle file:

> ' classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.12.+''

I had already tried

> 'gradle:0.12.2,  >gradle:0.13.+'  >gradle:0.11..+''
>   but still error occurs..
>   Please help me...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion you should:

1. Upgrade your Android Studio by checking updates (can be annoying, especially if your running versions older than 1.0.0)
2. Upgrade your project, using this line:

   ```
   classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.0'
   ```
3. If present, replace the line

   ```
       runProguard false (or true)
   ```

   with

   ```
       minifyEnabled false (or true)
   ```

within buildTypes / release in your `build.gradle` file.

4. Sync your project and see if it works.

If you can't figure out what's wrong I would try:

- building a new project with your new version of AS;
- uninstalling Android Studio and reinstalling from scratch (be sure not to delete your entire Android SDK)

Last option worked with me at the time.

Comment: still error coming: gradle dsl method not found: 'runProgram()'  the project 'myapp' may be using a version of gradle that does not contain the method

Comment: sure it's not `runProguard`? If so, replace with `minifyEnabled`

Comment: Yes it is runProguard(), and when I simply replace runProguard with minifyEnabled, it gives a flavorDimension error saying a specified dimension is non-existent.

Comment: Edited my answer. If this does not help, edit your question with this new info and wait for others.